# Unpredictable behavior in thread execution (Head First Java example)

Tags: java, multithreading

[image: page 498 of Head First Java]

First of all I don't know why they wrote the main method in the ThreadTestDrive class, then I went to their website downloaded this code below:

```
public class MyRunnable implements Runnable{

public void run()
{
    go();
}

public void go() {
    doMore();
}

public void doMore() {
    System.out.println("top o' the stack");
}

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Runnable threadJob = new MyRunnable();
    Thread myThread = new Thread(threadJob);
    myThread.start();
    System.out.println("back in main");
}}
```

Every time I run this code the output is always the "back in main" above the "Top o' the stack", it's not unpredictable as they said, why?

Comment: It's just by chance that it happens on your machine.

Comment: It looks like an error in their example. When you start your new thread, it will only run the Runnables "run" method and then exit. So, myThread.start() runs once . What is unpredictable is whether "top o.." or "bacK" prints first as their execution is separated into separate threads. I suspect the author intended this to be wrapped in a loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With recent multi core CPU it is "rather expected" that a so fast processing such as `System.out.println("back in main")` statement invoked in the current running thread happens before the new started thread be effectively running.
As in the output they get unpredictable behaviors very easily, I suppose they tested with a limited CPU.
Personally I think that they could have found an example where the result is most often/easily unpredictable.

For example create 4 (or more) threads that you start at the same time and you will easily see distinct behaviors.
As the threads are started "at about" the same time, you have here a real  concurrency between them for their execution :

```
public class MyRunnable implements Runnable {

    private int count;

    public MyRunnable(int count) {
        this.count = count;
    }

    public void run() {
        go();
    }

    public void go() {
        doMore();
    }

    public void doMore() {
        System.out.println("doMore(), count=" + count);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Thread(new MyRunnable(1)).start();
        new Thread(new MyRunnable(2)).start();
        new Thread(new MyRunnable(3)).start();
        new Thread(new MyRunnable(4)).start();
    }
}
```

Output (first try) :

> doMore(), count=2
>
> doMore(), count=4
>
> doMore(), count=3
>
> doMore(), count=1

Output (second try) :

> doMore(), count=1
>
> doMore(), count=4
>
> doMore(), count=3
>
> doMore(), count=2

Answer (score 1):

It is unpredictable means even if you try a million times and found out the code is executed in the same order, when the code is executed next time or in different environment, the execution order is still not guranteed by JVM.

It might be more easier to simulate this unpredictable behavior with more threads:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
    Runnable threadJob = new MyRunnable();
    Thread myThread = new Thread(threadJob);
    myThread.start();
    System.out.println("back in main");
}
```